# Loop through variables and sum specific variables to create a new variables

Tags: sas

I have a data set that contains monthly corp bond data over a time period and I have added on to it a spline interpolation of the risk free bond price curve going out 30 years ahead by month.  I have a variable "next_int" which tells me in how many months the next coupon is due and how many months left til maturity, "mnts_mat".

I also have a coupon frequency variable, "cf".  the spline bond prices are listed as var1, var2,...,var360.  I want to sum over the spline bond prices in months in which a coupon payment would be made.

So for a bond with the next interest payment due in a month and maturing in 13 months with a biannual coupon frequency, I would like to create a variable y=var1+var7+var13.  What I have written now is this:

```
data bond2 (DROP=i);
set bond1;
by issue_id date;
y=0
do i=next_int to mnts_mat by 12/cf;
y=y+var'i';
end;
run;
```

This doesn't work.  I have also experimented with creating a macro to that takes i as an argument and outputs vari, but that doesn't work either.  Any help would really be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand the nature of the problem, but here's some pointers:

- you need a semi-colon after "y=0"
- it looks like you need to declare an array for var1-var360
- once you've an array declared you can refer to something like var[i] (not var'i')

[Code]

```
data bond2 (DROP=i);
  set bond1;
  by issue_id date;
  array vars var1-var360;
  y=0;
  do i=next_int to mnts_mat by 12/cf;
    y=y+var[i];
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do it with array.